# how to create server-plugin in neo4j

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, neo4j

i m trying to make a Server Plugin for my neo4j database and i m following the tutorial below.

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-plugins.html

i just created a maven project and created a sample code.

> To deploy the code, simply compile it into a .jar file and place it
>   onto the server classpath (which by convention is the plugins
>   directory under the Neo4j server home directory).

what does compile it into .jar file mean? I just right clicked to project and i exported project as jar  is enough?

> The .jar file must include the file
>   META-INF/services/org.neo4j.server.plugins.ServerPlugin with the fully
>   qualified name of the implementation class. This is an example with
>   multiple entries, each on a separate line:

so how to do the above sentence?

Comment: Unless you have a good reason, you should prefer unmanaged extensions over server plugin to extend a neo4j server. Unmanaged extensions offer much more flexibility regarding http (used content types, request methods, parameter handling, ...).

Comment: @StefanArmbruster actually i m new in this technology. and i couldnt achieve anything. after than i m going to search what i need actually. Now i cant run hello world example

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:**

[Here](https://github.com/FylmTM/neo4j-server-plugin-example) you can find Neo4j server plugin example.

---

You can build *.jar using Maven build system.

Be sure that you have appropriate plugin enabled in your `pom.xml` file (probably in root directory).

Example (using `shade` plugin):

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Then you should run `mvn clean install` or `mvn clean package` from your root directory. After that you should have your `*.jar` in `target/` directory.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are new in the Java world.

Maven is a build tool with a command line.
To build the project & make the jar, just run this command :

```
mvn package
```

Answer (score 0):

> The .jar file must include the file
>   META-INF/services/org.neo4j.server.plugins.ServerPlugin with the fully
>   qualified name of the implementation class. This is an example with
>   multiple entries, each on a separate line:

just i opened the file and added the file after than i zipped the file and changed the extension rar to jar.

and i use mvn clean package to create jar file.